Fatal Python error: init_import_site: Failed to import the site module
My linux machine is in python3.9.6 I am trying to upgrade it to python3.12.3 using the below commands

./configure --enable-optimizations
make
sudo make install

But I am facing this error in the "make" step
Fatal Python error: init_import_site: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Python-3.12.3/Lib/site.py", line 73, in <module>
    import os
  File "/root/Python-3.12.3/Lib/os.py", line 29, in <module>
    from _collections_abc import _check_methods
SystemError: <built-in function compile> returned NULL without setting an exception
make[1]: *** [Python/frozen_modules/abc.h] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/Python-3.12.3'
make: *** [profile-opt] Error 2
[root@auto-controller Python-3.12.3]#

I tried "make clean", "./configure --enable-optimizations" and again "make" still the same error

Unless you really know what you're doing, you should not be installing Python from source and especially not sudo make installing it to circumvent your distribution's package manager – you'll likely end up with a broken system if you do this. If your distribution doesn't ship a new enough Python, you can use e.g. pyenv to install an alternate Python in an user-specific directory.
